# onEachFeature not working in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am making a map in which I am showing details of the feature on click event. The event is working fine. I am also highlighting the feature on another click event. For this I am adding an extra layer of the feature that has been clicked on the map and I am providing a button to deselect that feature so that the extra layer is removed from the map.

The problem here is that when I click on the deselect button the property of the first click event is lost i.e. onEachFeature function does not called.

I don't have idea why is this happening?

Comment: Any chance you could share your code, and if possible reproduce your issue online? (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/18/)) It would be much easier to help you then.

Comment: sorry, it's not possible to share the code, but I will try to reproduce it on jsfiddle..